# Which file based DBMS should I support in an open source project?

Tags: open-source, database

I am working on an open source project which can use a number of DBMS' as backend. So far we supports SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 but we would also like to support some additional databases including some file based DBs.

Note: The file based databases must work on a 64-bit platform, so MS Access is not an option as there is no 64-bit provider AFAIK.

Which DBMS should a database centric open source project support in your opinion?

Comment: Just for the record: The project is for windows only and in C# (framework 3.5) We'll add support for SQLite first and perhaps Firebird (embedded) second. For the time being I see no reason to support MySQL or similar when a SQL 2008 express is for free, but perhaps one day I might see the light :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), definitely.

Comment: ( +1 for being a faster typist that me. 8-)

Answer (score 3):

Provide ODBC support, then the end-user can choose from just about any database going.

Comment: Unless you have a very generic database with lowest common denominator features this won't really work well.

Comment: It will work very well, and does so for thousands of applications. Have you ever actually programmed ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org), either in its embedded variant or as a (small footprint) server.

Comment: +1 for Firebird. See here to know more http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL](http://mysql.org), it's a widely used free/open source RDBMS.

Not a file based DBMS, but you didn't say it had to be, only that you wanted a few of those too.

Answer (score 0):

Support these: sqlite,mysql,postgresql

You don't mention what language you're developing in. Some, like Java, have standard database APIs, so supporting multiple SQL servers is easy, provided you can use the common denominator of the SQL language in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that firebird can be better than SQL Lite and M$SQL Express , or even is better than mysql , scales better with the number of CPUS and is more mature (triggers , and transactions are implemented for many many light years ago)